# Pronunciation: TH in "There"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, th

This might be a silly question, but I've noticed that **some** people in the US don't pronounce their "**TH's**" in some words such as **(This, that, the, these, those and etc...)** and some other people don't even bother pronuncing it in words such as "**there**" either. Is it me or people really do drop that "**TH**" sound in the word "**there**"? If so, how common is it to hear something like that?

Here are some example phrases where I've heard no **TH** coming from the word **"there"** in American English:

> I'm going over **der**. (There)
>
> Did you go **der**? (There)
>
> Did you see that **der**? (There)

Comment: You need to give better examples of what you mean. Phoneme substitutions are certainly made in American dialects, and in some cases that particular phoneme can be dropped or slurred, but you need to provide more examples *in context*.

Comment: How should the examples be?

Comment: Full sentences, and say where you heard them.

Comment: See if you find your answer [in this excellent answer on our sister site](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/278886/2303).

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-stopping